# como generar un txt con jquery utilizando cmd?

Tags: jquery, cmd

necesito ejecutar el comando para obtener la direccion ip de la maquina del cliente, ejecutando "ipconfig" en un cmd, el cual seria generado desde un jquery...

tengo esto en javascript

```
  function RunFile() {

    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    WshShell.Run("cmd /c ipconfig > c:/programa.txt", 0);

  }

RunFile();
```

y me genera el archivo con la direccion ip, posteriormente, al cargar otra pagina, esta me lee el archivo generado y obtengo la direccion ip, sin embargo, necesito realizarlo con jquery... por peticion del usuario, ya que despues esto se migrará para utilizar otros navegadores como chrome(actualmente se utiliza en IE9).

Alguien tiene idea de como realizarlo? ya busqué en muchas paginas y no encuentro nada parecido.

Aprecio su apoyo.

Comment: es decir deseas obtener la direccion IP del cliente con Jquery/JavaScript ?

Comment: exacto!!! de preferencia con Jquery.